# Nested XML data and ExtJS model associations

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs, nested, associations

I'm trying to map XML data to a series of models in ExtJS. I'm able to extract the data from the toplevel model, however, the associations with it fail to retrieve the necessary data.

Here are all of my models:

```js
Ext.define('app.model.ProductType', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        mapping: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        mapping: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'sometag',
        mapping: 'sometag',
        type: 'string'
    }],
    associations: [{
        type: 'hasMany',
        model: 'app.model.Address',
        name: 'addresses',
        autoLoad: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'address',
            root: 'addressList'
        }
    }, {
        type: 'hasMany',
        model: 'app.model.PhoneContact',
        name: 'contacts',
        autoLoad: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'phoneContact',
            root: 'phoneContactList'
        }
    }, {
        type: 'hasOne',
        model: 'app.model.OneToOne',
        name: 'oneToOne',
        autoLoad: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'oneToOne'
        }
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/example.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'ProductType',
            root: 'ProductResultSet'
        }
    }
});
```

Address:

```js
Ext.define('app.model.Address', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'city',
        mapping: 'city',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'street',
        mapping: 'street',
        type: 'string'
    }],
    associations: [{
        type: 'belongsTo',
        model: 'app.model.ProductType'
    }]
});
```

PhoneContact:

```js
Ext.define('app.model.PhoneContact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'primary',
        mapping: 'primary',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'cell',
        mapping: 'cell',
        type: 'string'
    }],
    associations: [{
        type: 'belongsTo',
        model: 'app.model.ProductType'
    }]
});
```

OneToOne:

```js
Ext.define('app.model.OneToOne', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'first',
        mapping: 'firstfield',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'second',
        mapping: 'secondfield',
        type: 'string'
    }],
    associations: [{
        type: 'belongsTo',
        model: 'app.model.ProductType'
    }]
});
```

Here's my app.js

```js
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'app',
    autoCreateViewport: false,
    requires: ['app.model.ProductType', 'app.model.Address', 'app.model.PhoneContact', 'app.model.OneToOne', 'app.store.ProductTypeStore'],
    launch: function () {
        app.model.ProductType.load(55, {
            scope: this,
            callback: function (record, operation) {
                console.log('Record Addresses:');
                console.log(record.addresses());
            }
        });

        var s = app.store.ProductTypeStore.create();
        s.on('load', this.wiggidy, this);
        s.load();
    },
    wiggidy: function (store, records, success, eOpts) {
        var rec = store.getAt(0);
        console.log('Associated Data:');
        console.log(rec.getAssociatedData());
    }
});
```

And finally, example.xml

```
<ProductResultSet>
<ProductType>
    <id>55</id>
    <name>Product Name</name>
    <sometag>asdf</sometag>
    <addressList>
        <address>
            <street>12345 a</street>
            <city>myCity</city>
        </address>
        <address>
            <street>234567 b</street>
            <city>Denver</city>
        </address>
    </addressList>
    <phoneContactList>
        <phoneContact>
            <primary>234</primary>
            <cell>4667</cell>
        </phoneContact>
        <phoneContact>
            <primary>5467</primary>
            <cell>87904</cell>
        </phoneContact>
    </phoneContactList>
    <oneToOne>
        <firstField>value</firstField>
        <secondField>value</secondField>
    </oneToOne>
</ProductType>
</ProductResultSet>
```

The console spits out "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined" for the RecordAddresses output, and then I get an object filled with arrays with 0 objects for the Associated Data output.

I'm completely stumped on this one. I've searched around everywhere and it's taken me this far. Why is the record not loading the nested data in that xml file?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will you be able to post your working sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you setting autoLoad=true in the hasMany relationship?

You are trying to use nested data, and then you are telling it to load the data on demand, and wondering why there is no nested data :)

You are also missing the associationKey, which is required for nested loading.

Here is a working example of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/el_chief/668Fg/5/

Follow my "Rules" in the future and everything will be ok:

http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/05/extjs-hasmany-relationships-rules.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. I love the "rules" section - Looks like I broke almost every one of them :D. I can't upvote you at the moment because I need to have a reputation of 15. I'll give the links you gave me a try and if I have success I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe what fixed it was the associationKey. Thanks a bunch! I'll be sure to upvote your answer once I am able to.